# Python: Testing for unicode, and converting to time()

Tags: python, django

Sometimes self.start is unicode:

eg.

```
>>>self.start
u'07:30:00'
```

Which makes datetime.combine complain

```
start = datetime.combine(self.job_record.date, self.start)
```

How does one:

1. Test for unicode?
2. Convert from u'07:30:00' to datetime.time?

Comment: add the actual error message!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`datetime.combine` is complaining because it expects the second argument to be a `datetime.time` instance, not a string (or unicode string).

There are a few ways to convert your string to a `datetime.time` instance.  One way would be to use `datetime.strptime`:

```
t = datetime.strptime(self.start, "%H:%M:%S").time()
start = datetime.combine(self.job_record.date, t)
```

Answer (score 4):

Checking for unicode:

```
>>> import types
>>> type(u'07:30:00') is types.UnicodeType
True
>>> type('regular string') is types.UnicodeType
False
```

Converting strings to time:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.strptime(u'07:30:00', '%H:%M:%S')
(1900, 1, 1, 7, 30, 0, 0, 1, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there won't be extended charset characters in '07:30:00', then use `str(self.start)`.

If there is a possibility that the numbers in the time are charset-specific, use `encode()`, with an appropriate `error` argument specifier to convert to string.

This may be a cases where it is more pythonic to try `str()` first and use `except` to handle cases that can't be converted (ask forgiveness rather than permission). If most of the values you are trying to convert fail, on the other hand, convert them first before applying the function.

As an unwanted aside: the `combine` function expects a datetime.date object and a datetime.time object. If you really want to avoid unpredictable behaviour, then meet the requirements of the API and pass `date` and `time` objects, rather than trying to short-circuit the contract specified by the documentation: convert the arguments **before** you call `combine`, rather than asking `combine` to guess for you.